# HW Raid - Centos 5 - Boot Issues

Tags: centos, boot, raid, boot-loader, raid1

I am totally lost as to how to fix this or what to do, I am about to just removed the raid all together. (Work stuff though, so Id rather not)\

I have a tower with 4 drives in it. 2 separate raids

```
2x 500gb
2x 1000gb
```

I want to install the OS on the 500 GB drives.

This is a HW raid, and the computer has had CentOS 5 installed before successfully.

I have tried using defaults, creating LVM's, using ext3 and manually creating /boot / swap etc.

In the last attempt I used both raids in default config which made an LVM and just got the grub prompt. When i manually created /boot /root and swap on the 500GB raid partition, I got

no root (hd1,0)

then the grub prompt

Tried re-installing Grub via Rescue CD, but still didn't work.

I am new to Hardware raid, I use mdadm at home. Anybody got any suggestions?

How can I install CentOS 5.5 on a raid partition?

The previous installation had the following config:
/dev/md124 -1TB
/dev/md124p1  just for data

/dev/md126 - 500GB
/dev/md126p1 /boot
/dev/md126p2 SWAP
/dev/md126p3 /

One thing I do notice in GParted in the old config they were mounted on `/media/md124p1`, but I couldn't use anything like that during HD layout config in CentOS. Little lost, if you need more information, please let me know

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the boot order through your raid controller bios. Seems like it tries to boot from the other LV (i.e. your 1TB array).

Answer (score 0):

I had to boot a LiveISO then edit the grub.conf, I wasn't exaclty sure it would work, but I just uncommented an already existing line that specified the boot drive.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd1,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/isw_eajhcidchc_Volume0p3
#          initrd /initrd-version.img
#THE BELOW LINE WAS COMMENTED OUT AND UNCOMMENTING IT FIXED THE ISSUE
boot=/dev/mapper/isw_baiehbdebb_Volume1
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd1,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-194.11.1.el5)
        root (hd1,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=/
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-194.11.1.el5.img
[root@localhost ~]#
```